# Create relationship between two existing nodes in STRUCTR.org

Tags: neo4j, structr

I created my database in "SCHEMA-Editor" from structr.org. I have two nodes "Project" and "ProjectManager" and relationship between these is "MEMBER". 
I made a cypher query to create the graph like this:

```
MATCH (a:Project),(b:ProjectManager)
WHERE a.name = 'X' AND b.name = 'Y'
CREATE (a)-[r:MEMBER]->(b)
RETURN r,a,b;
```

And i expected to display the graph, but i got this message: "MEMBER.id must_not_be_empty"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nodes and relationships created with Cypher are not immediately usable in Structr, because Cypher bypasses the Structr layer and acts directly on the database level. There are some extra steps that need to be done to make an object known to Structr: it needs an `id` attribute that contains a random UUID (universally unique identifier).

See "Tools" -> "Admin" -> "Relationships" -> "Add UUIDs" in the Schema Editor.

Additional tip: in Cypher, you should use MERGE instead of CREATE to avoid creating duplicate relationships between the two nodes (depending on your use-case).

Comment: Thanks. I have one more misunderstanding: For example a ProjectManager has many Projects and I want to display the graph with all the informations created in "Data-Field" also with relationship between nodes and for this i wrote this command:  Match (n) return (n). Should I write a separately cypher code to create the relationship between the projects and the manager, it's not enough the schema?

Comment: MATCH (m:Project { title: 'Proj' })<-[:MEMBER]-(ProjectManagers) RETURN ProjectManagers.name;   I want to return all ProjectManagers that are Member in 'Proj'.

Comment: All that can be done very easily in Structr, no need to use Cypher for simple queries like that. Please have a look at repeater elements (https://support.structr.com/article/275), StructrScript (https://support.structr.com/article/119) and especially the find() function (https://support.structr.com/article/53).

Comment: To answer your Cypher question: the query to return the project managers would be:

MATCH (p:Project { title: 'Proj' })<-[MEMBER]-(m:ProjectManager) RETURN m

Comment: Thanks for the previous answer.